# \textnumero and font encoding

Tags: latex, special-characters

I currently use the \textnumero sign in my LaTeX document. Therefore, I need to include the 'textcomp' package. When doing so I get a compiler error stating:

> ! Package textcomp Error: Symbol \texnumero not provided by
>     (textcomp)                font family ptm in TS1 encoding.
>     (textcomp)                Default family used instead.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textcomp]

%... somewhere in the document
\textnumero ...
```

How can I get rid of this message? Can I set some other font or encoding for the number sign only?

Many Thanks,
Ovanes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about LaTeX.

Comment: It should not be closed, but moved to latex or tex stackexchange forums. When I asked the question in 2009 there were no such forums in stackexchage sites, so we used stackoverflow to ask that sort of questions.

Comment: This question is too old for migration - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/153020 for details. The only people with the power to migrate older questions are the community managers/developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Changing to font which has this sign solved the issue.

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\savesymbol{iint}
\usepackage{txfonts} % this is the font
\restoresymbol{TXF}{iint}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}



\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Note! savesym package is now needed to avoid errors, that iint is already defined.

Regards,
Ovanes

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the bother of changing fonts (for example, you want to keep times), try this:

```
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\newcommand{\ftextnumero}{{\fontfamily{txr}\selectfont \textnumero}}

...
\ftextnumero 1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}
```

(taken from [here](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?68035-Package-textcomp-Error-Symbol-textrightarrow-not-provided-by))